# CodeIgniter Join/Overset Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to access my Mysql database and I have two tables (News and Events) with the column ID. I figured I could use a select before (also tried after) using the 'as' keyword to return the News ID column as NewsID but it returns the NewsID and overwrites the ID column still. Below is some code to show an example.

```
$this->db->join('News', 'News.ID = Events.NID', 'left');
$this->db->where('Events.ID', $ID);
$this->db->get('Events');

//tried this before and after the join and added to the condition
$this->db->select('*, News.ID as NewsID');
```

Any Information or ideas would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Huh?  What are you trying to do?  Get the News ID?  What result are you expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to do a join between Events and News and I want the ID to be the Events ID column, but the News ID column to be NewsID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
select('Events.*, News.ID as NewsID')
```

Comment: That works but any ideas if I wanted all the News columns, but only the News.ID to be NewsID.

Comment: It would be best to type out all the columns and then only alias the ID.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I ended up doing, but I really wish there was a better way. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually good practice anyways.  If your table ever changes, it won't affect your code.